# Is it possible to create new types of FitNesse SLIM fixtures for .NET?

Tags: .net, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim, fitsharp

I'd like to create a new fixture type in the .NET flavour of FitNesse, similar to Fabrizio Cannizzo's [RestFixture](https://github.com/smartrics/RestFixture), which is written in Java.  RestFixture can be used with both FIT and SLIM and I would like my .NET version to also work with both FIT and SLIM.

In FIT it's possible to create a new fixture type in .NET since the fixture classes are defined in the .NET test runner, FitSharp, and they can just be extended. 
 However, I understand that in SLIM the fixture classes are included in FitNesse, not in the test-runner, and FitNesse is written in Java.  So does that mean we can't create new fixture types for SLIM in .NET?

If it is possible to create a new fixture type for SLIM in .NET, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. SLIM fixtures can only be written in Java.  This is one of the limitations of SLIM (or benefits, depending on your point of view!)

Comment: Thanks Mike.  Having had a closer look at the RestFixture examples I realise that Fabrizio didn't create a new fixture type for SLIM after all.  While he did create a new fixture type for FIT, for SLIM he used a Table Table.  Which makes perfect sense, given how flexible the Table Table is.

Comment: Mike, am I missing something? As far as I know slim fixtures can be in many languages, as long as there is a slim server for that language. Only the tables are limited to Java, are they not?

Comment: @FriedHoeben: I find the terminology confusing, especially in FIT where "fixture" seems to refer to both the base classes that define table types, like ColumnFixture and DoFixture, and the classes that individual users create to test specific systems under test.  In my question I was using "fixture class" to mean the base classes that define table types.  In SLIM they would define table types like the DecisionTable or the QueryTable.